# Passing manifest file from remote url with kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to submit the resource to Container using Kubernetes CLI.

The below is what I use to submit jobs.

```
kubectl -n namespace create -f <manifest file PATH>
```

I am actually running this on a LINUX server which would meet application team requirement and provide this service for the users to use it.

The Challenge is I don't want to store the application teams Configuration files(*.yml/*.json) in the LINUX server and call it from the LOCALPATH instead call the configuration file remotely.

I think of BITBUCKET. Can someone please assist me on how we can call the file from remote location so that `kubectl` can accept it?

Appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 6):

You can use pipe with `kubectl` command to achieve it.

For example,

```
curl <your file url> | kubectl apply -f -
```

Here is a working example:

```
curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hossainemruz/7926eb2660cc8a1bb214019b623e72ea/raw/d9505d06aee33e0144d9f2f9107290f1aba62cd5/mysql-initialization-with-init-container.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Emruz. I get the below error when I run the curl.


curl --silent https://bitbucketdc.jpmchase.net/users/RAM/repos/KUBECTL/browse/job1.yml | kubectl apply -f -
error: no objects passed to apply

I think because BITBUCKET expects username and password

Comment: At first, make sure you are able to view the file using just `cur <url>`. your url does not provide the file while i try to curl.  It gives me `<a href="http://ww2.bitbucketdc.jpmchase.net">Moved Permanently</a>`. you have to use raw url. if you only use curl to the file i have given in example, it will print the yaml in terminal.

Comment: Thanks Emruz i figured it out and curl is working well. Appreciate your timr

Answer (score 4):

In case someone stumbles over this in the future,
with the current version (v1.26.5+k3s1) of kubectl you can use

```bash
kubectl apply -f <url>
```

directly as long as the url returns raw text.
For example raw.githubusercontent.com urls (what you get when you hit "raw" on the file viewer on GH) works.